# How do I create a List of Widgets taking properties from multiple lists?

Tags: android, flutter

I want to create a list of widgets depending on the content of two or three dynamically generated lists.

```
List<String> Sound = ['A','B','C'];
List<String> Number = ['1','2','3'];
List<int> vertical = [10,20,30];
List<int> horizontal = [20,30,40];

 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Row(
            children:  Sounds.map((sound) {
              return FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: () => _audioCache.play(Sound),
                  child: Text(Number),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

Using the map function it seems like I can only build a list of Floating action buttons with one property. I want to give each button created by the map function properties from multiple different lists. How can I achieve that? This build function is in the state class of a stateful widget.

Comment: Use List.generate and return a Widget instead of an int here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/List.generate.html

Comment: `children: [for(int i=0; i<Sound.length; i++) SomeWidget(Sound[i], Number[i], vertical[i], horizontal[i])]`

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Uni's comment, here is a simple Dart program that shows the use of `List.generate` to create a list of Maps from two lists - your code would create your widgets:

```
void main() {
  List<String> Sound = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
  List<String> Number = ['1', '2', '3'];
  var list = List.generate(
      Sound.length, 
      (i) => {'Sound': Sound[i], 'Number': Number[i]},
  );
  print(list);
}
```

BTW it is recommended to name non-constant identifiers using lowerCamelCase, so `Sound` should be `sound`.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally remodel the data.

If you are always using the same index of each list to build the widget why not make the a class with a sound and a number as properties then have one list of those objects.

Then the map you have would just be over those objects